# Exclude specific site from search result

Tags: support, search

In Google, we can use minus (-) operator to remove one site from the results.

Example:

> [Change div tag color -stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=change%20div%20tag%20color%20-stackoverflow.com)

How can I do this when I search **using stackexchange.com search**?